# R read.csv encoding

Tags: r, csv, encoding, character

I am trying to read my data with this code:

```
List <- read.csv("List.csv", sep = ";")
```

My data "Yıldız" shows like Yýldýz

When I use this code:

```
List <- read.csv("List.csv", sep = ";" , encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

It shows like this : Y�ld�z

I search a lot before I wrote here but none of them helped me. Can you help me fix this? I use turkish language.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried? Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "Turkish")

Comment: Thank you so much. You helped me a lot. It seems easy but I spend so much time on this. So happy right now.

Comment: No worries, glad I helped!

Answer (score 0):

That i found is you need to use ISO-8859-9 for encoding.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Turkish_characters

Comment: Yes. It is also known as Latin-5. But didnt work for me either.